# How to convert vectors to arrays in ECLiPSe (CLP)? (or Prolog)

Tags: arrays, prolog, eclipse-clp

I have to solve Sudoku puzzles in the format of a vector containing 9 vectors (of length 9 each).  Seeing as vectors are linked lists in Prolog, I figured the search would go faster if I transformed the puzzles in a 2D array format first.

Example puzzle:

```
puzzle(P) :- P = 
[[_,_,8,7,_,_,_,_,6],
[4,_,_,_,_,9,_,_,_],
[_,_,_,5,4,6,9,_,_],

[_,_,_,_,_,3,_,5,_],
[_,_,3,_,_,7,6,_,_],
[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,8,9],

[_,7,_,4,_,2,_,_,5],
[8,_,_,9,_,5,_,2,3],
[2,_,9,3,_,8,7,6,_]].
```

I'm using ECLiPSe CLP to implement a solver.  The best I've come up with so far is to write a domain like this:

```
domain(P):-
  dim(P,[9,9]),
  P[1..9,1..9] :: 1..9.
```

and a converter for the puzzle (parameter P is the given puzzle and Sudoku is the new defined grid with the 2D array).  But I'm having trouble linking the values from the given initial puzzle to my 2D array.

```
convertVectorsToArray(Sudoku,P):-
  ( for(I,1,9),
      param(Sudoku,P)
    do
      ( for(J,1,9),
          param(Sudoku,P,I)
        do
          Sudoku[I,J] is P[I,J]
      )
  ).
```

Before this, I tried using array_list (http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/termmanip/array_list-2.html), but I kept getting type errors.  How I did it before:

```
convertVectorsToArray(Sudoku,P):-
  ( for(I,1,9),
      param(Sudoku,P)
    do
      ( for(J,1,9),
          param(Sudoku,P,I)
        do
          A is Sudoku[I],
          array_list(A,P[I])
      )
  ).
```

When my Sudoku finally outputs the example puzzle P in the following format:

```
Sudoku = []([](_Var1, _Var2, 8, 7, ..., 6), [](4, ...), ...)
```

then I'll be happy.

**update**

I tried again with the array_list; it almost works with the following code:

```
convertVectorsToArray(Sudoku,P):-
  ( for(I,1,9),
      param(Sudoku,P)
    do
      X is Sudoku[I],
      Y is P[I],
      write(I),nl,
      write(X),nl,
      write(Y),nl,
      array_list(X, Y)
  ).
```

The writes are there to see how the vectors/arrays look like.  For some reason, it stops at the second iteration (instead of 9 times) and outputs the rest of the example puzzle as a vector of vectors.  Only the first vector gets assigned correctly.

**update2**

While I'm sure the answer given by jschimpf is correct, I also figured out my own implementation:

```
convertVectorsToArray(Sudoku,[],_).
convertVectorsToArray(Sudoku,[Y|Rest],Count):-
  X is Sudoku[Count],
  array_list(X, Y),
  NewCount is Count + 1,
  convertVectorsToArray(Sudoku,Rest,NewCount).
```

Thanks for the added explanation on why it didn't work before though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution is to avoid the conversion altogether by writing your puzzle specification directly as a 2-D array.  An ECLiPSe "array" is simply a structure with the functor `'[]'/N`, so you can write:

```
puzzle(P) :- P = [](
    [](_,_,8,7,_,_,_,_,6),
    [](4,_,_,_,_,9,_,_,_),
    [](_,_,_,5,4,6,9,_,_),

    [](_,_,_,_,_,3,_,5,_),
    [](_,_,3,_,_,7,6,_,_),
    [](_,_,_,_,_,_,_,8,9),

    [](_,7,_,4,_,2,_,_,5),
    [](8,_,_,9,_,5,_,2,3),
    [](2,_,9,3,_,8,7,6,_)).
```

You can then use this 2-D array directly as the container for your domain variables:

```
sudoku(P) :-
    puzzle(P),
    P[1..9,1..9] :: 1..9,
    ...
```

However, if you want to keep your list-of-lists puzzle specification, and convert that to an array-of-arrays format, you can use `array_list/2`. But since that only works for 1-D arrays, you have to convert the nesting levels individually:

```
listoflists_to_matrix(Xss, Xzz) :-
    % list of lists to list of arrays
    ( foreach(Xs,Xss), foreach(Xz,Xzs) do
        array_list(Xz, Xs)
    ),
    % list of arrays to array of arrays
    array_list(Xzz, Xzs).
```

As for the reason your own code didn't work: this is due to the subscript notation `P[I]`. This

- requires `P` to be an array (you were using it on lists)
- works only in contexts where an arithmetic expression is expected, e.g. the right hand side of `is/2`, in arithmetic constraints, etc.